# How to view OTF fonts?

Tags: text-object

Blender only shows TFF fonts, on all versions I've tried (Windows 10).

The problem: When you add text (add>text), and you go to the font modifier tab, attempt to change font, and navigate to system fonts, only TFF fonts show up (even if filter disabled). OTF fonts do not show up. All fonts are installed properly and show up in other programs (Maya, Photoshop, Illustrator, Absolutely Everything Else).

My personal workaround: I've been using maya for any text, and then exporting it as OBJ into blender.

Anyone know how to make blender support OTF fonts? Seems strange that maya supports this and blender doesn't.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I found this on the blendernation site:

> Blender supports all the major fonts supported by the freetype library, including PostScript Type1 and Type3, TrueType, and OpenType. However fancy OpenType features such as automatic ligatures aren't supported and it **seems** Blender doesn't even support things like built-in kerning metrics either.

So, you may find an .OTF that works. But if you're pressed for time, convert it to .TTF, or one of the other abovementioned, with e.g. http://www.freefontconverter.com

Comment: ...it says automatic ligatures and maybe kerning metrics are not supported, but to me it doesn't naturally sound like the characters of the fonts are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

It appears windows only links files to the Font directory and hence Blender does not 'see' them. Try open the same font in another directory and Blender will see it.

Information from here: https://developer.blender.org/T61398

Comment: For me that worked! Thanks Patdog!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there are "special" OTF fonts that Blender can't handle, but I have fonts in other directories than the system font directory as well.

So when I go to the *Text Properties* and click on *Open Font*, Blender opens the default Windows > Fonts directory with the installed fonts. Then I simply change to a different directory just like I would do with any other load/save dialogue when I want something in a specific location.

I navigate to the folder where I have my other fonts and there all OTF fonts show up and I can use them for the text object.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem.
see, when you are in blender font selection.
just put the directory of the font you want.
it'll appear :)

[image]

Comment: Hello, your solution doesn't seem to highlight .otf fonts, which is the topic of the question. Are you sure you're really answering the question ?